# Dependent function template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say that I want the return value of a function template to be determined by the some template argument. I can use `auto`:

```
template<int>
auto foo2();

template<>
auto foo2<5>() {
    return std::make_optional(5.0);
}
```

However, it's not clear to me how this is possible without `auto`. Let's say my function template is:

```
template<int, typename T>
std::optional<T> foo();

template<>
std::optional<double> foo<5, double>() {
    return std::make_optional(5.0);
}
```

To use this, I now need to specify both parameters. Is there any way around this? I guess with a class I could do a partial specialization with a default value for the second parameter, but not with a function.

Comment: But there is a rule to determine the `T` type from the `int` value?

Comment: @max66 sort of. Instead of an `int`, there is an enum and each enum value maps to a certain class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want, anyway...

Without `auto`, I suppose you can add something to pass from the integer (or enum) value to the requested `T` type.

For example... you can add a custom type-trait as follows

```
template <int>
struct get_type;

template <>
struct get_type<0>
 { using type = int; };

template <>
struct get_type<1>
 { using type = long; };

template <>
struct get_type<5>
 { using type = double; };
```

so `foo()` become something as

```
template<int I>
std::optional<typename get_type<I>::type> foo ()
 { /* ... */ }
```

When your `int` values start from zero and are sequential, instead of a custom type-traits you can use a `std::tuple`.

I imagine something as

```
using type_list = std::tuple<char, int, long, long long, float, double>;

template <std::size_t I>
std::optional<std::tuple_element_t<I, type_list>> foo ()
 { /* ... */ }
```